# Two components with different props change each other in React

Tags: reactjs, dom

I am experiencing a very weird bug when one component in `React` changes another even though I would expect them to be completely isolated from each other. So, I have three components in the parent and I supply them with different props:

```
     <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1} id="cluster-tabs">
        <Tab eventKey={1} title="cells">
          <ClustersMultiChart type="cells" datum = {this.props.mainData} allGenesData={this.props.allGenesData}
            datasetName = {this.props.datasetName} page = {this.props.page} pageNames = {this.props.pageNames}/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={2} title="genes">
          <ClustersMultiChart type="genes" datum = {this.props.mainData} allGenesData={this.props.allGenesData}
            datasetName = {this.props.datasetName} page = {this.props.page} pageNames = {this.props.pageNames}/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={3} title="reverse">
          <ClustersMultiChart type="reverse" datum = {this.props.mainData} allGenesData={this.props.allGenesData}
            datasetName = {this.props.datasetName} page = {this.props.page} pageNames = {this.props.pageNames}/>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
```

`ClustersMultiChart` can be one of `3` different types: `cells`, `genes` or `reverse`. The bug happens in the `reverse` type. First I am doing request to the server with `axios` to get the data for the `reverse` component. The right data comes and initially updates the state with correct `clusterData` variable which is an array. Then the `DOM` starts updating and during it the `clusterData` array is changed even though (!) no other methods of the component itself are called. Here is the `axios` request:

```
handleSearch = () => {
if (!this.state.loading) {
  this.setState({
    loading: true
  });
  let url = '/cluster?datasetName=' + this.props.datasetName;
  url = url + '&geneNames=' + this.state.selectedGeneNames.join(",");
  let that = this;
  axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    const clusterData = response["data"]["clusterData"];
    if (that.state.maxVal > 0) {
      that.fixMax()
    }
    that.setState({
      clusterData: that.state.clusterData.concat(clusterData),
      loading: false,
      allAddedGenes: that.state.allAddedGenes.concat(that.state.selectedGeneNames),
      selectedGeneNames: []
    });
 });
} else {
 alert("Wait! It is loading.");
}
}
```

So, I am setting breakpoint in nearly every method and I see that first `clusterData` is having the right data, but then, at each `DOM` update of the code of the other component, a new array is added to the `clusterData`:

```
<div className={this.props.type === "cells" ||
      (this.props.type === "genes" && this.state.clusterData.length) ? "" : "hiddenDiv"}>
    {
    this.props.datum.map((clusterObj, idx) => {
      return <div>
        <Col xs={4} md={4} style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
          <Well>
            <Label bsStyle="primary">Cluster {idx + 1}</Label>
              <div className={!this.state.loading && (this.props.type === "cells" ||
                this.props.type === "genes" && this.state.clusterData.length) ? "" : "hiddenDiv"}>
                <BarChart type = "cluster" cluster = {this.props.datasetName + "_" + (+idx + +1)} width = {300} height = {100}
                  datasetName = {this.props.datasetName} dataArr = {this.getDataForBarChart(idx)} maxVal = {this.state.maxVal}/>
              </div>
          </Well>
          </Col>
      </div>
 })
```

Above you see the `map()` function. Since after `handleSearch` the `state` changes, this part of `DOM` is updated and the `this.getDataForBarChart(idx)` is called at each `map()` iteration. Making breakpoint in `this.getDataForBarChart(idx)` function I see that in between the calls the `clusterData` gets new data from literally nowhere. I do not know how to track it down. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just figured out that the `this.getDataForBarChart(idx)` during `DOM` updates was doing that. I fixed it by checking the `type` of the component:

```
getDataForBarChart = (idx) => {
if (this.props.type === "cells" || this.props.type === "genes") {
  let chartData = this.state.clusterData[idx];
  let geneNames = geneNameArr[this.state.geneNameArrIdx]["genes"].split(",");
  if (this.props.type === "genes") {
    geneNames = this.state.allAddedGenes;
  }
  if (chartData) {
    let presentGenes = chartData.map((geneArr) => {
      return geneArr[0];
    });
    geneNames.map((geneName, idx) => {
      if (presentGenes.indexOf(geneName) === -1) {
        this.addZeroGene(chartData, geneName);
      }
    });
    chartData.sort(this.sortFunc);
    return chartData;
  } else if (chartData == null) {
    chartData = [];
    geneNames.map((geneName, idx) => {
      this.addZeroGene(chartData, geneName);
    });
    return chartData;
  } else {
    return chartData;
  }
}
}
```